# Which ski resorts in western Europe offer free lifts (intended for families)?

Tags: children, winter-sports, western-europe

A lot of people with small children (who can't ski very well) would like to spend some time teaching them skiing, but ideally not pay high fees for the ski-pass for this time. Which ski resorts in western Europe (i.e. in the Alps, Pyrenees, Sierra Nevada, etc.) offer a short lift for free for the benefit of families? I am after resorts that also offer first-class skiing for adults, so have a big network and wide variety of ski-runs.

If I recall correctly, Val Claret in the Tignes region had a chair lift for free, but I was there a few years ago, so it might be not correct...

Comment: A lot of resorts have either free lifts or "beginners" areas which are cheaper than the full domain.

Comment: I can see in your profile that you are from london so I guess you are not looking for some places in India...

Comment: Could you reduce your search area to a country or continent?  At present your question is way too broad...presumably you're eyeing up an area to visit?  Closing for now, but you're used to the site - please edit and flag to reopen when you've edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMayo, thanks for your comment. I narrowed it down, hopefully will be helpful for other people now as well.

Comment: I think it's still way too broad. I picked a random resort in France (near Nice) and there is a beginner area, that costs less than the full domain : http://winter.isola2000.com/daily-pass Also, in France at least, the resorts targeting first-class skiing for adults and those targeting families with young children are usually not the same.

Comment: @Vince, while a reduced cost beginner area is surely useful, the question was specifically about free areas.

Comment: To be honest, if you're paying thousands of pounds to travel somewhere, it shouldn't be too difficult to spend a few pounds on a pass.

Comment: @DarkLightA, this is a fair point. However, the pass is more like a few hundred pounds for a week, and it costs pretty much the same to go to an area with free lifts.

Answer (score 5):

Val Thorens has multiple moving carpets: Castor and Pollux, Musaraigne and Campagnols. Free, and easy for small kids. Roc is a small draglift, so less suitable.

http://www.valthorensguide.co.uk/beginners-area.html

In the next valley there's Courchevel 1850, which has three longer lifts: Cospillot, Bellecote, and Etoiles.

http://www.courchnet.com/lifts/ski/options.html

Apparently the free lift in Val Claret isn't that nice either for young kids, so Tignes-le-Lac might be a better option.

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/snowandski/france/tignes/6762169/Tignes-piste-guide.html

Comment: you forgot to add all these resorts have a pretty large domain. As for Tignes, I think the slope served by the Bollin chairlift is good enough, while very busy. And Tignes/Val d'Isere (partnering resorts) have quite some free lifts for beginners: http://www.tignes.net/fr/ski-a-tignes/plan-des-pistes-28.html (dashed on the map)